# String to Key-Value pairs in spark dataframe (No Pyspark)

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

Example:
I have a column with a string. I need to convert this into a tuple or an array. The main challenge is that I need the key as integer and value as Double.  Array<Int, Double>.

It'd be great if someone provides me with an idea or a suggestion?

Comment: , instead if : is fine for the implementation??

Comment: Actually they are a key-value pair. so any special character would be fine ":" or "-" . Using a "," would be confusing to distinguish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the string provided in the question and the required output needs to be a `Array[(Int, Double)]`

Input data:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val values = List("1:1.10, 2:2.20, 3:3.30")

val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
val df = values.toDF()
```

Creating an UDF:

```scala
def parse_values(value: String) = {
      val values = value.split(",").map(_.trim)
      values.foldLeft(Array[(Int, Double)]()){
        case (acc, present) =>
            val Array(k, v) = present.split(",")(0).split(":")
            acc :+ (k.trim.toInt, v.trim.toDouble)
      }
}

val parse_values_udf = udf(parse_values _)
```

Using the UDF:

```scala
df.withColumn("parse_value", parse_values_udf(col("value")))
```

validation of the output:

```
scala> df.withColumn("parse_value", parse_values_udf(col("value"))).show(false)
+----------------------+------------------------------+
|value                 |parse_value                   |
+----------------------+------------------------------+
|1:1.10, 2:2.20, 3:3.30|[[1, 1.1], [2, 2.2], [3, 3.3]]|
+----------------------+------------------------------+

scala> df.withColumn("parse_value", parse_values_udf(col("value"))).schema
res22: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(value,StringType,true), StructField(parse_value,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(_1,IntegerType,false), StructFi
eld(_2,DoubleType,false)),true),true))
```

Comment: Hey Pavithran, Thank you so much for your solutions. Is there a way to get the final output as a single list instead of lists of list?'